# EF6 Cannot insert duplicate key row

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, inversion-of-control, repository-pattern

I got error when i try to update entity with unique constraint
I checked the form and there were a couple of similar post but none has answer.

```
    public class Car
    {
         [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int IdCar { get;set; }

        public string ColorCode { get; set; }

        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public string MotorId { get; set; }
    }

     private static int UpsertCar(Car checkCar, IUow uow)
    {
        var car =
           uow.Cars.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.MotorId.Trim()
               .Equals(checkCar.MotorId.Trim(),
                   StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (car == null)
        {
            uow.Cars.Add(checkCar);
            uow.Commit();
            return checkCar.IdCar;
        }
        else
        {
            car.ColorCode = checkCar.ColorCode;
            uow.Cars.Update(car);
            uow.Commit(); // Issue when i try to save
            return car.IdCar;
        }
    }
```

Here is the update function

```
 public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {

            DbSet.Attach(entity);
        }  
        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Error

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Car' with unique index 'IX_MotorId’.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: when you update use the `car` instance instead of `checkCar`,

Comment: Why do you check for MotorId when looking for the car rather than IdCar (very strange naming BTW)?

Comment: Well naming is not the issue, and this is the logic of the application

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you chose to use the Repository pattern over the top of Entity Framework - an architecture problem. This isn't the only problem you'll have in your solution.

EF6 is very powerful, and the repository pattern hides all that power.

A standard way to code this whole upsert concept involves loading the original record from the context:

```
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IdCar { get;set; }

    public string ColorCode { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string MotorId { get; set; }

    //By having this update function alongside the members, it's easy to see whether it's up to date.
    public void Update(Car original)
    {
        original.ColorCode = ColorCode;
        original.MotorId = MotorId;
    }
}

public static int UpsertCar(Car checkCar, MyContext db)
{
    var original = db.Cars.SingleOrDefault(c => c.IdCar == checkCar.IdCar);

    if (original == null)
    {
        db.Cars.Add(checkCar);
    }
    else
    {
        checkCar.Update(original);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here you can see how simple it is when using EntityFramework directly.

Importantly, you can also see how simple it is to create your own Update function (keeping your current ORM architecture). Often, business rules will restrict what is able to be updated, and your own Update function won't allow update of all fields.

You should never need to use `dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;` and if you do, you're probably approaching the code incorrectly.